# Vagrant: How to upgrade from PHP5 to PHP7?

Tags: php, vagrant, ansible

Currently my `playbook.yml` contains:

```
tasks:
    - include_vars: vars.yml
    - name: install packages
      apt: name={{ item }} update_cache=yes state=latest
      with_items:
      - git
      - nginx
      - php5
      - vim
      - php5-mysqlnd
      - php5-curl
      - php5-xdebug
      - php5-gd
      - php5-fpm
      - php5-intl
      - php-pear
      - php5-imap
      - php5-mcrypt
      - php5-ming
      - php5-ps
      - php5-pspell
      - php5-recode
      - php5-sqlite
      - php5-tidy
      - php5-xmlrpc
      - php5-xsl
      - fail2ban
      - rsync
      - beanstalkd
      - supervisor
      - redis-server
```

Comment: Why was it down voted? I know about `apt-get` but some how packages were not available. I had no choice but to ask here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're running ubuntu, you should replace all the php related with something like

```
- name: PHP | Install Ondrej PHP PPA
  apt_repository: repo='ppa:ondrej/php' update_cache=yes

- name: PHP | Install PHP 7.0
  apt: pkg=php7.0 state=latest
  tags: common

- name: PHP | Install PHP Modules
  apt: pkg={{ item }} state=latest
  tags: common
  with_items: "{{php_modules}}"
```

You can search for php7 compatible mode but this is a good starting point

```
  vars:
    php_modules:
      - php7.1-mysql
      - php7.1-gd
      - php-apcu
      - php7.1-mcrypt
      - php7.1-curl
      - php7.1-intl
      - php-memcached
      - php7.1-mbstring
      - php7.1-xml
      - php7.1-pgsql
```

Comment: But when I am searching via `apt-cache search php7` it returns nothing.

Comment: did you configure the repo ?

Comment: Configuring of what?

Comment: did you re-run the playbook or add the ppa:ondrej/php repo manually ?

Comment: Ah yes I re-provisioned and this time I can search `PHP7` related packages but I see some packages like `mysqlnd` are not available? will it make any difference?

Comment: php7.0-mysql contains mysqlnd (see https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/php7.0-mysqlnd) you'll probably need to review the list and find a matching one for php7 if its not straightforward replacement of 5 by 7